# Is there a way to run a scala sheet in Intellij on a remote environment?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am looking for a way to run some scala code in a spark shell on a cluster. Is there a way to do this? Or even inside a simple scala shell where I can instantiate my own spark context.
I tried to look for some kind of Remote setup for scala worksheet in Intellij but I wasn't able to find anything useful.

So far the only way I can connect to a remote environment is to run the debugger

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have come across is that on the spark cluster install the jupyter notebook.

Now you can use the browser and work remotely on the cluster. Otherwise good old telnet also works.

Comment: how do you use telnet for this?